# SQL: Count (*) WHERE multiple matches are expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum

The query I wish to build is the following:

1. find all `video` matching `categoryId` field
2. find `history` records for each of them
3. and finally to count/sum them together.

The query I managed to build so far is:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM "histories" as "history" 
 WHERE "history"."videoId" = 
                  (SELECT "id" 
                   FROM "videos" 
                   WHERE "videos"."categoryId" = '9f5a0e6f-512b-425a-9225-600f876c0105' ))
```

I guess you can clearly see through where the problem is already. I'm selecting all records, where `videoId` is equal to... a list of ids. SQL doesn't buy it.

```
SQL ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The "workaround" I've found was to limit the `video` rows to just one. But of course, that wouldn't give me a full output.

I'll highly appreciate all the tips, or maybe even answers.

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: @VBoka I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Just change `=` to `IN`

Comment: @Nick Oh wow! Thank you so much! If you wish to post an answer, please go ahead and I'll mark it appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the `=` operator to `IN`:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM "histories" as "history" 
 WHERE "history"."videoId" IN  
                  (SELECT "id" 
                   FROM "videos" 
                   WHERE "videos"."categoryId" = '9f5a0e6f-512b-425a-9225-600f876c0105' ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to note that you can also use `= any`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "histories" as h
WHERE h."videoId" = ANY (SELECT v."id" 
                         FROM "videos" v
                         WHERE v."categoryId" = '9f5a0e6f-512b-425a-9225-600f876c0105'
                        );
```

I would strongly advise you to dispense with the double quotes around identifiers.  They just clutter queries.